# tcolorbox in a sublevel of enumerate containing verbatim

Tags: enumerate, tcolorbox, verbatim, pythontex

I would like the `codepy` box defined below to start either:

- to a new line,
- or its width be reduced so that it does not overlap with number `1.1]`
  How to do this ?

When tcolorbox contains a `verbatim` environment, the box covers the number.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,xcolor,pythontex}
\usepackage[skins,breakable,xparse,many]{tcolorbox}
%
\DeclareTColorBox{codepy}{ o }{
      skin=enhancedmiddle jigsaw, % Rule D/G uniquement
      enlarge top initially by = 2.5mm,
%      parbox=false,
      rightrule=0mm,
      leftrule=2mm,
      arc=0mm,
      outer arc=0mm,
      left=3.4mm,
      coltitle=white,
      titlerule=0mm,
      detach title,
      attach title to upper={\ \quad \ },
      IfValueTF={#1}{title={#1}}{},
}
%
\setlist{nolistsep,
         leftmargin = *}
%
\setlistdepth{3}
%
\newlist{myEnumerate}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[myEnumerate,1]{label=\arabic*),ref=\arabic*,labelwidth=2em,leftmargin=!,wide}
\setlist[myEnumerate,2]{label=\arabic{myEnumeratei}.\arabic*],ref=\themyEnumeratei.\arabic*,labelwidth=2em,align=left,leftmargin=!}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{myEnumerate}
\item 
    \begin{myEnumerate}
    \item
\begin{codepy}
Test
\begin{pyverbatim}
x = 1   
\end{pyverbatim}
\end{codepy}
    \end{myEnumerate}
\end{myEnumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: comment out `parbox=false`. By the way, if the contents is short, may be you want to consider a `\tcbox` instead of a `tcolorbox`.

Comment: I just edited my question. In fact, the problem always occurs as soon as the box contains a `pythontex` environment.